# Percentage based question on consumption

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The price of raw materials has gone up by 15%, labour cost has also
>   increased from 25% of the cost of raw material to 30% of the cost of
>   raw material. By how much percentage should there be reduction in the
>   usage of raw materials so as to keep the cost same?

Initial cost:

$$R+L$$

$$=R+\frac{1}{4}R$$

Final Cost

$$\frac{115}{100}R+\frac{3}{10}\frac{115}{100}R$$

ATQ

$$\frac{5}{4} R*C=\frac{115}{100}\frac{13}{10}R*C'$$

$$C'=\frac{250}{299}C$$

Therefore,

Required percentage=

$$=\frac{49}{299}*100$$

,which comes close to 16.38 percent.

However the answer given is 17%. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: I also get $16.34\%$ with some quick calculations of my own.

Comment: maybe the result is simply rounded

Comment: As to why it's rounded down, I guess that to be slightly realistic, it's a good idea to reduce the actual cost while maintaining the nominal cost (and sell at the same price).